# How to peek inside function from library

Tags: c#, dll, webmatrix

I have an assembly WebMatrix.WebData.dll and
I want to look inside the body of one of the functions and to see how it is implemented
The function name is: WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);

It is in namespace WebMatrix.WebData

I am just curious to see how everything is working down there.
Is it possible to extract the body to a user-friendly code?

Comment: In response to this being put on hold: The proper answer has nothing to do with tool recommendation as this is an open source stack - and that seems to be something that not enough people know about. Surely it's worth getting the word out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to go downloading decompilers for anything in the ASP.NET web stack, it's open source! You can read it all through in it's fully commented and unobfuscated glory. Here is a link to the exact line of the method you're after:

https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs#L318

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of decompilers out there.

http://ilspy.net/ - ILSpy (Free)

http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ - DotPeek (Free)

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/ - Reflector (Trial/Paid)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ILSpy to decompile a library into source code.

Download it here: [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)